# What would happen if a team would let the draft timer run out?

Tags: ice-hockey, draft

Watching the NHL draft and teams are 'on the clock'... They only have a few minutes to announce their pick.

But what would happen if a team, by inadvertance, let that timer run out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a team fails to get their pick in before the clock expires, the next team in the draft order is allowed to pick instead. Once that next pick is made, the original team can then use their "missed" pick.

It doesn't happen very often, but it does happen. The most common scenario for a "missed pick" is if the team on the clock is planning to trade picks with another team but the negotiations break down at the last minute, leaving them scrambling to make a move.